# Silverlight border from images

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I would like to make generic control, that will have nice border and inside content presenter (this will be: left top corner [image: border-left-top])

That is a way I've chosen to do it, given the fact there is no tiled image brush.
I've predefined tiles (10 is enough for all scenarios in my application). It works, however I have to specify width/height for this border control explicitly, as the predefined tiles are enlarging the grid. Is there a way how to make it resize automatically according to width/height of content, or some different more elegant way ?

```
<sfc:UserControlEx x:Class="Barbar.D20.SilverClient.Views.Controls.UI.Border"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sfc="clr-namespace:Barbar.SilverFramework.Controls;assembly=Barbar.SilverFramework"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left-top.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right-top.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left-bottom.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right-bottom.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="25,0,25,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,25,0,25" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,25,0,25" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
        </StackPanel>    
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="25,0,25,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Margin="25,25,25,25" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" />
    </Grid>
</sfc:UserControlEx>


using System.Windows.Markup;
using Barbar.SilverFramework.Controls;
[ContentProperty("UserContent")]
public partial class Border : UserControlEx {
  public Border() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public object UserContent {
    get { return contentPresenter.Content; }
    set { contentPresenter.Content = value; }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I ended up with this solution (creating my own StackPanel that "hides" resulting size), also I moved from UserControl to ContentControl due to referencing x:Name="" items inside content control; still if anyone knows more elegant way, I would like to know:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace Barbar.SilverFramework.Controls {
  public class NoSizeStackPanel : Panel {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty =
              DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Orientation",
            typeof(Orientation),
            typeof(NoSizeStackPanel),
            new PropertyMetadata(Orientation.Horizontal, null));

    public Orientation Orientation {
      get {
        return (Orientation)base.GetValue(NoSizeStackPanel.OrientationProperty);
      }
      set {
        base.SetValue(NoSizeStackPanel.OrientationProperty, value);
      }
    }


    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) {
      var children = Children;
      for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++) {
        children[i].Measure(availableSize);
      }
      return new Size(0, 0);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize) {
      // Get the collection of children
      var children = Children;
      double w = 0;
      double h = 0;
      double mh = 0;
      double mw = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++) {
        var point = (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) ?
           new Point(w, 0) : new Point(0, h);

        double dw = children[i].DesiredSize.Width;
        double dh = children[i].DesiredSize.Height;

        mh = Math.Max(mh, dh);
        mw = Math.Max(mw, dw);

        w += dw;
        h += dh;

        children[i].Arrange(new Rect(point.X, point.Y, dw, dh));
      }

      return (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) ?
        new Size(w, mh) : new Size(mw, h);
    }
  }
}

using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace Barbar.D20.SilverClient.Views.Controls.UI {
  public class Border : ContentControl {
    public Border() {
      this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Border);
    }
  }
}

<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:sfc="clr-namespace:Barbar.SilverFramework.Controls;assembly=Barbar.SilverFramework"
    xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:Barbar.D20.SilverClient.Views.Controls.UI"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="ui:Border">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ui:Border">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left-top.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right-top.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left-bottom.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                        <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right-bottom.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                        <sfc:NoSizeStackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="25,0,25,0">
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-top.png" Stretch="None" />
                        </sfc:NoSizeStackPanel>
                        <sfc:NoSizeStackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,25,0,25" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-left.png" Stretch="None" />
                        </sfc:NoSizeStackPanel>
                        <sfc:NoSizeStackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,25,0,25" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-right.png" Stretch="None" />
                        </sfc:NoSizeStackPanel>
                        <sfc:NoSizeStackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="25,0,25,0">
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image Source="/Images/Border/border-bottom.png" Stretch="None" />
                        </sfc:NoSizeStackPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="25,25,25,25" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Stretch` property of `Image` with `Fill` value. With `RenderTransform` you can use just 3 pictures...

```
<Grid>
    <Image
        Source="/Images/top.png"
        Height="25"
        Margin="25,0"
        Stretch="Fill"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Image
        Source="/Images/top.png"
        Height="25"
        Margin="25,0"
        Stretch="Fill"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image
        Source="/Images/left.png"
        Margin="0,25"
        Stretch="Fill"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Width="25" />
    <Image
        Source="/Images/left.png"
        Margin="0,25"
        Stretch="Fill"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Width="25"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image
        Source="/Images/corner.png"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="25"
        Height="25" />
    <Image
        Source="/Images/corner.png"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="25"
        Height="25"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image
        Source="/Images/corner.png"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Width="25"
        Height="25"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image
        Source="/Images/corner.png"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Width="25"
        Height="25"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleY="-1" ScaleX="-1"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <ContentPresenter
        x:Name="contentPresenter"
        Margin="25,25,25,25"
        Width="Auto"
        Height="Auto" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Upvote, however not an answer :) the problem with this approach it prolongs non-corner images (left,top,right) so instead of repeating texture you have one stretched to desired size. If you're interested I can post solution I found in the meantime, but it is huge (I ended up creating my own panel).

Comment: With a shader effect ? And update the effect each time the area changes size ?

Comment: I've seen solution using pixel shader, but I'm trying to stay away from that (not sure if mobiles will have GPU acceleration). I've updated the question to give you an idea what I've done.